# How can I calculate the time complexity of Google Sheets formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, time-complexity

There are many ways to write single-purpose formulas in Google Sheets. For example, I can use the `Vlookup` function and `Filter` together to look up data with two condition columns, the `&` operator and `vlookup` together, `offset`, `index`, and `match` together.

I need to create a sustainable document that can handle ever-growing data. Is there any way to calculate the time complexity of a Google Sheet formula?

I'm already doing things like using array formulas where appropriate, using validation, and avoiding recalculation-heavy functions like now().

I'd like to be able to accurately measure performance time in situations where I'm confused: (e.g.) reducing the number of cells I use and increasing the complexity of the formula vs. simplifying the formula by adding a single field.